# Writing and reading form external storage after an app has been uninstalled - Why does this work?

Tags: java, android, file

I was having trouble coming up with a title for my confusion but hopefully it portrays my question well.

I have made an app that requires a couple of permissions. When the app starts, I check for a first time setup. Although this is most likely a very inefficient and wrong way of going about this, I created a file that contains a Boolean on whether this is, in fact, the first time opening the app. I am also using the external storage, which is probably the worst way to go about it, but it was the only way I knew how to do it so I went with it. Below are my methods for getting data and retrieving it.

```
public static void serializeDataOutBoolean(boolean b) {
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + '/';
        File newFile = new File(path + "writeBoolean.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeBoolean(b);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static boolean serializeDataInBoolean(){
    try{
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + '/';
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path + "writeBoolean.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        boolean iBool = ois.readBoolean();
        ois.close();
        return iBool;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if I open it up for the first time and the file doesn't exist, this will return false, meaning that this is a first time setup and I need to check for permissions. Then once the user has accepted all the permissions, I will set this Boolean to true, so I know in the future not to run the first time setup.

My question is as follows: If I install the app, grant permissions and I write true to this file, then uninstall the app, the file is still present. I can go into my files folder (I am using an s8) and go to internal storage and see the file that I have written. I assume that that file contains a Boolean "true" because that was the last thing I wrote to it. Now if I reinstall the app, for some reason it performs the first time setup, even though the file exists already and there was a true written. (This is obviously what I want).

But I just don't understand why it is doing what I want. Shouldn't my dataIn method see that there is a file named `"writeBoolean.txt"` and see that it is populated with a true value and skip this process?

**EDIT**

As someone pointed out, I totally forgot to include where I am calling these methods, sorry.

```
boolean testingFirst = MyService.serializeDataInBoolean();
    if(!testingFirst) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Permissions.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

if this is a first time setup (false) then it runs my permissions class which will then write a true to the file once it is done via: `MyService.serializeDataOutBoolean(true);`

Besides this method, I also know that the value is being set to true by continually checking it every 10 seconds using my service class that I have set this up for. Using this very scientific chunk of code:

```
String testingString = "WHAT DOES THIS CONTAIN???????? " + String.valueOf(serializeDataInBoolean());
System.out.println(testingString);
```

I am able to confirm that the file does indeed contain the Boolean: true.

Thank you for your help, and if anyone thinks of a better title feel free to edit it.

Comment: In the code you've provided, I don't see any tests to check true in the file you've mentionned.

Comment: @JFPicard sorry, added that in

Comment: You've edited the question yet again to change the code and I've noticed that the code within the functions keeps changing. It's good that you're improving the code, but it makes it hard to know whether your problem is with the code you posted, or some other change you're making since the code is clearly in flux.

Comment: @iheanyi Actually, I haven't changed any code, I was tired yesterday and didn't notice that I kept on posting the wrong bits of code. First, I posted half of my serializeOut for one of my methods and half for another. You pointed that out in your answer yesterday, and I foolishly removed the one that had to do with my edit and added the wrong one. I didn't want to comment again because, to be honest, it was very embaressing that someone was helping me and I kept on giving the wrong information. I apologize for wasting your time, but the code up there right now is the pertinent code.

Comment: Have you confirmed that a **true** is being written to the file? I see you catch exceptions in `serializeDataInBoolean()` then return false - are you sure that the `readBoolean()` is succeeding?

Comment: Yes, two ways. First is, that my if statement under my edit only ever works once, because I set the value to true in my Permissions.class. Also, I checked it using a SOP and printing the value of the Boolean in the file, which happens to be true.

Comment: @iheanyi something I just noticed after reading your edits, It seems to throw a `FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)` when I try to install it with the file present. Is it being blocked out, making a new file and overwriting the previous file??? I just don't understand why it would throw a permission denied for a new instance of the same application when I can also grab this file from other applications as well.

Comment: Cool, we're on the right track. Your code seemed more or less correct so I suspected a potential access issue with the file. So, you likely have write permissions on external storage in your manifest, do you also declare your app needs **read** permissions? NM, getting write permission implicitly gives you read!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150436/discussion-between-iheanyi-and-cjnash).